# Do Westworld episodes sometimes include bonus content (behind-the-scenes, interviews, etc.) on some platforms?

Tags: alternate-version, westworld-tv

Watching through *Westworld*, I have noticed that my downloads from iTunes are shorter than the displayed length on, for example, Amazon VoD. The 90-minute finale is displayed as "1 hour, 35 minutes" on Amazon, for example. Other episodes also have longer durations—only by a few minutes, but still.

Am I missing out on bonus content or extra scenes by watching iTunes downloads? I don't have an HBO subscription, so I can't actually watch Amazon's versions, but I'm curious what's going on, especially since the longer times are what end up in my Trakt history.

Comment: Is it possible that it's just an error? [IMDb lists it](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5229638/?ref_=ttep_ep10) as being 90 minutes, too...

Comment: Um... [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MYVUNFE?ref_=imdbref_tt_wbr_aiv&tag=imdbtag_tt_wbr_aiv-20) lists it as being "1 hour, 35 minutes"....

Comment: That said, I don't think the downvotes are justified if that's all it was. If I'm off topic, that's another matter.

Comment: I have HBO Go and after each episode there's a short featurette with a quick discussion with a writer or director or something... they do it for Game of Thrones, too... I don't **know** this is what is on the Amazon version but it's possible....

Comment: That seems like the most likely reason. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure.... there's no close votes...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this questions seems to be more about the viewing service rather than the show itself.

Comment: I will add that I didn't make that vtc lightly.  I think this could potentially be edited to be more on-topic.  But, as it stands it seems off-topic to me.

Comment: I will retitle the question, since I'm really asking if there is extra content available through a different viewing service (i.e., does bonus content exist, and am I just in the wrong place to get it).

Comment: Also note that iTunes generally has the additional content if you purchase the season. But they usually show up as separate episodes. They will often number them differently, too. If the episodes are number 1, 2, 3, etc., then the extra content will usually be listed as episodes 101, 102, 103, etc.